# Having height of last row take all the space with rowspan

Tags: html, css

I have a table structure like this

[image]

And the html structure is this

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Hierarchy</th>
           <th>Operations</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
            <td class="history-hierarchy" rowspan="4">
               <div><!-- Tree structure is loaded here dynamically --></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td class="history-text">
                  Equipment A700/005 is added. 
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td class="history-text">
                  System instance SYSI/0002 is added. 
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td class="history-text">
                  Equipment 7100/001 is replaced with 7100/002  
              </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you see the image, the `Operations` columns height is adjusting itself based on the `Hierarchy` columns height, I am looking for some way if possible to have the heights of operation column fixed say `10px` and whatever space is left the last row's operation column should consume it.

So the operations column will not looke weird having so much height.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you got any CSS to accompany this post?

Answer (score 0):

the approach you are using is correct, you can use `rowspan="2"` on the last row as shown in my snippet.

```css
table {height: 600px}
table td {border:1px solid red; vertical-align:top}
td.history-text {height: 20px}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Hierarchy</th>
           <th>Operations</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
            <td class="history-hierarchy" rowspan="4">
                <div>Tree structure is loaded here dynamically</div>
            </td>
            <td class="history-text">
                  Equipment A700/005 is added. 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="history-text">
                  System instance SYSI/0002 is added. 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td class="history-text" rowspan="2">
                  Equipment 7100/001 is replaced with 7100/002  
             </td>
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```